# Flex CSS issue with IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, flexbox

Here is my CSS Code:

```
.title_content {
    display: flex;
}

.video_title {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 25px;
    padding-right:100px;
}
```

And there, my HTML code:

```
<div class="title_content">
    <h1 class="video_title">
       A long text which don't want to be flexed in IE
    </h1>
</div>
```

That works on Firefox and Chrome but not in IE.

Comment: I check your code. here all things work. what's problem with you? which IE version you are using?

Comment: IE 10 and before don't support this syntax.

Comment: Check can I use for flex suppot http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox